# Shiny.i18n text decoration

Tags: shiny, internationalization, translation

I am translating all texts in my Shiny-app with Shiny.i18n, using the live approach.
I am having a realtive long Text in my app, which I want to be able to translate but also at the same time make individual words in that text bold.

I know that I could theoretically write and translate each word individually and then make it bold. But I would like to find a more elegant option that lets me make words within a larger context bold.

Here is a repex of my problem.

The Shiny-App

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.i18n)
library(ggplot2)

i18n <- Translator$new(translation_json_path='translation.json')
i18n$set_translation_language('de')



ui <- fluidPage(
  shiny.i18n::usei18n(i18n),
  h1(i18n$t("Welt")),
  tags$div(
    style='float: right;',
    selectInput(
      inputId='selected_language',
      label=i18n$t('Change language'),
      choices = i18n$get_languages(),
      selected = i18n$get_key_translation()
    )
  ),
  h1(i18n$t("<strong>Hallo</strong> Welt"), windowTitle=NULL),
  
  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$selected_language, {
    update_lang(session, input$selected_language)
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have my translations saved in a json e.g.

```
   "languages":[
      "de",
      "en"
   ],
   "translation":[
      {
         "de":"<strong>Hallo</strong> Welt",
         "en":"<strong>Hello</strong> World"
      },
      {
         "de":"Sprache Aendern:",
         "en":"Change language:"
      },
      {
        "de":"Welt",
        "en":"World"
      }
   ]
}
```

If i now try to change the language only *"World"* is translated. *"< strong >Hallo< /strong > Welt"* does not get translated at all. I dont understand why.

If I add `h1(i18n$t(HTML("<strong>Hallo</strong> Welt"))`. *"Hallo"* does get bold, but the sentence is still not translated.

I have also tried `h1(HTML(i18n$t("<strong>Hallo</strong> Welt"))`, but this throws the following error message:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument is not a character vector

Thank you very much for any advice or any ideas

Comment: The problem is that with the use of `usei18n` the content of the original json is stored here and there in the DOM using `htmltools` functions like `span`. BUT: the text ist  **escaped** and suddenly you have a mismatch, which prevents the auto translation. You can get the code running by using `h1(i18n$t(HTML("<strong>Hallo</strong> Welt")))`  but the translation won't work b/c of the aforementioned reasons. Bottom line: do not use the auto translation with `use18n` or fall back to single words and keep markup out of the json.

Answer (score -1):

First things first, a [Full Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) will halp in the future to get proper answers, as you do not require the people who are dedicated some of **their** time to **your** problem to first create a running example.

Regarding your problem. You need to tell `shiny` to render the text as `HTML`. See the use of `HTML` in the example below.

### `translation.json`

```
{
   "languages":[
      "de",
      "en"
   ],
   "translation":[
      {
         "de":"<strong>Hallo</strong> Welt",
         "en":"<strong>Hello</strong> World"
      },
      {
         "de":"Sprache ändern:",
         "en":"Change language:"
      }
   ]
}
```

### `app.R`

```r
library(shiny)
library(shiny.i18n)
translator <- Translator$new(translation_json_path = "translation.json")

ui <- fluidPage(
   titlePanel('Use HTML in Translation'),
   uiOutput('page_content')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   i18n <- reactive({
      selected <- input$selected_language
      if (length(selected) > 0 && selected %in% translator$get_languages()) {
         translator$set_translation_language(selected)
      }
      translator
   })
   
   output$page_content <- renderUI({
      tagList(
         sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
               selectInput('selected_language',
                           i18n()$t("Sprache ändern:"),
                           choices = translator$get_languages(),
                           selected = input$selected_language)
            ),
            mainPanel(
               ## note the use of `HTML` here
               p(HTML(i18n()$t("<strong>Hallo</strong> Welt"))) 
            )
         )
      )
   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot showing the bold word in the translation]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have now added a repex. Unfortunately your solution does not work for me. I think it is because I translate my app a little bit different, but I am not sure. Do you have any other advice/idea?